# how to set default font size on Froala Editor?

Tags: javascript, fonts

I set default font size to 30;

```
$('#QBody').froalaEditor({
                fontSizeDefaultSelection: '30',
                fontSizeSelection: true });
```

When the editor is loaded for the first time and I first clicked for typing then change the font size of the editor immediately

I think by default editor font size has been adjusted from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML tag probably has CSS styles that change the font-size properties. Try to set that to something you need to be specified, for example if you are using textarea, i will just do it inline like:

```
<textarea id="QBody" style="font-size: 30px;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the froala editor options.

This was suggested by official froala tech support.

```
events: {
        initialized: function(editor){
          // console.log("editor", editor._editor)
          //here we are setting the default values
          editor._editor.events.focus();
          editor._editor.fontSize.apply('16px');
          editor._editor.fontFamily.apply('Open Sans Condensed, sans-serif');
          editor._editor.lineHeight.apply('1.5');
          editor._editor.colors.text('#4a4a4a');
        }
}
```